# Freezing Headers in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, scroll

I've seen many posts here and elsewhere with people having issues freezing headers in Reporting Services.   Most of the issues are with people not understanding how to use the FixedData propertly on Static rows.  Once they understand that, they get it working.

I am past all those issues.   I have the frozen headers working just fine.   My problem is, it's only working in reportviewer.aspx.   It isn't working in report.aspx (Report Manager).   None of my research to date shows anyone else having this problem.  And, I have seen posts stating very specifically that they have it working in report.aspx.    I'm at a loss at this point as to what the problem might be.

I'm running SSRS 2012 (Version 11.0.3369.0 of the designer) and IE 9.

Comment: My first suspicion is that are not looking at the same version of the report when you go to report.aspx.   Try uploading your latest version again and verifiying the upload took place and you are looking at the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but they are the same version of the report.  I just tested by redeploying after some additional changes to the report.  The changes show up in both report.aspx and reportviewer.aspx.   It's very puzzling.